# Titanium: Best way to manage user settings

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, appcelerator

I'm writing my first titanium app and am wondering what is the best way to manage a users settings.

Part of the app includes creating a quote. I want to give the user the ability to set a quote reference number start. So it'll be 'Q0001' say but the user can change it to 'QUOTE0001' so I have a text field on a settings page where the user woulod enter 'Quote' and it is then prepended to a incrementing number.

Is it best to store this in a config file, or database? Or does Titanium have a set way of doing config variable?

Thanks,

Billy

Answer (score 1):

I would use properties for that: [Titanium](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.App.Properties-module)

Simply use Titanium.App.Properties.setString("username", textfield.text);

Comment: thanks for the reply, how would I set a default value, that can be changed, but then does't get overwritten again when the app is loaded?

Comment: Also I'm getting an error 'Ti.Properties' [undefined] is not an object

Comment: Note you have to use Ti.App.Properties

Comment: Sorry, yes, you have to use "Titanium.App.Properties.setString..."